# Copy data from one sheet of Google Sheet to another with script and web-app

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is my first script experience. I have to make two types of Spreadsheet. One is for sellers, another is for manager. The data from seller's sheet with script button are importing to manager's sheet. I need to use web-app because seller shouldn't see manager's spreadsheet.

This is my broken code. The part for sellers script:

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var TEST = spreadsheet.getRange("B4").getValue();
var TWO = spreadsheet.getRange("B5").getValue();
var THREE = spreadsheet.getRange("B6").getValue();
var FOUR = spreadsheet.getRange("B7").getValue();
var FIVE = spreadsheet.getRange("B8").getValue(); 

function myFunction() {
  var data = "[new Date(), TEST, TWO, FIVE, FOUR, THREE ];"
  UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://script.google.com/a/***/exec', {payload: data}); 
};
```

And web-app:

```
var SHEET_ID = '***';

function doPost(e){
  SpreadsheetApp.openById(SHEET_ID).getSheets()[0].appendRow(e.postData);
}
```

Could you tell me, what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there were a few things wrong with the code. The following example works OK. But it uses the model that the seller's (source) spreadsheet pushes the data to the Manager's (destination) spreadsheet, which is the published web app.

You could of course do this using a pull model, where the web app is in the source spreadsheets and the data is pulled into the destination speadsheet. Which is best all depends upon factors like how many spreadsheets are there going to be, how often do they change, and your overall security model, etc.

---

### `Button handling code in the source / sending spreadsheet.`

```
function called_by_button(data_to_be_sent){
          // Make some test data.
          var data = {
            'date': new Date(),
            'first': 'data1',
            'second': 'data2'
          };

          var options = {
            'method' : 'post',
            'payload' : data,
            muteHttpExceptions: true
          };
          // This is probably the best way to use UrlFetchApp() and handle errors.

      var url = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/your-url-here/exec';

      try {
        var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options); // Post the data (make the HTTP Request)
            var responseCode = response.getResponseCode();
            if (responseCode === 200) { // 200 = SUCCESS
              Logger.log("url_fetch() response code %s ", responseCode);
              return response; 
            } else {
              Logger.log(Utilities.formatString("url_fetch() Request failed for: %s, Expected 200, got %d",url,responseCode ));
              return false; 
              // 
            }
          }// end Try
          catch (err) {
             Logger.log(Utilities.formatString("url_fetch() Request failed (underlying network error). %s, response code: %s",err, responseCode));
             return false;
          } 
   }
```

---

### `doPost() published as a web app from the destination spreadsheet`

This picks apart the values sent and logs one in each row. Note that because the destination app is bound to the destination spreadsheet it doesn't need to find and open it using `openById()`. If you made this a standalone script then it would have to do that.

```
function doPost(e){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ws = ss.getActiveSheet();
  ws.appendRow([e.parameter.date]);
  ws.appendRow([e.parameter.first]);
  ws.appendRow([e.parameter.second]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer! I made as you've suggested and pushed the button. Any data haven't apeared in destinantion spreadsheet. No alarming messages. I feel upset.

Comment: @OpenReligion Is there anything in the Log Viewer (View menu >> Logs) on the sending side? Perhaps you should just add `ws.appendRow(["I was called"]);` at the start of the doPost() function to see if it is being called?

Comment: That's from Logs:
[19-01-22 22:57:13:861 MSK] url_fetch() Request failed (underlying network error). ReferenceError: Object "url" is not defined., response code: 401

Comment: @OpenReligion ignore url not defined, minor glitch I've fixed in the code above. 401 error is an authorization problem. Re-publish the App as "Anyone, even anonymous" as answer to "Who has access to the app:" question, which may fix it. But visit [this page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) and explore the topics of [authorization](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization) and [permissions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#permissions). As I doubt "Anyone, even anonymous" is a suitable security model for your app.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now connection between spreadsheets is ok. But data drives me nuts. I need to copy values from particular cells and past it all in one row. When I try to set particular cells for data copying, it becomes "undefined" on another spreadsheet. Could you show me, how to use var TEST = spreadsheet.getRange("B8").getValue();  var data = "[new Date(), TEST ];" in your code and how to put in only in one row and two columns. I'm sorry, I feel shame.

Comment: @OpenReligion you need `output_range.setValues(data);` where, in your case, `data` needs to be a multi-dimensional array that matches the size of the range. So what I think you need is  
`var output_range = ws.getRange("C8:D8");  
var data = [[new Date(), TEST]];  
output_range.setValues(data);`  
I won't modify my original answer as Stackoverflow works on a 1 question = 1 answer basis, otherwise it gets too complicated. If my answer has satisfied your original question then please mark it complete.`